# Is there a way to round down DateTime with FluentDateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

The `Round(FluentDate.RoundTo.Hour)` method in [FluentDateTime](https://github.com/FluentDateTime/FluentDateTime) rounds the time to nearest hour, however I want to always round it down. Is there a package that can do that? FluentDateTime doesn't seem to offer that functionality.

Comment: You might as well just create your own extension method for that, to be honest.

Comment: That's not what I ask. I understand that I can create an extension, but I was looking for an existing solution, that I can reuse in multiple projects.

Comment: Well if you're shopping for an alternative library, that's off-topic...

Comment: I guess you're right. I can think of many solutions to the rounding DateTime, but I was just looking for an existing solution that can be reused in multiple projects.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new `DateTime` object, and zero out the minutes and seconds:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now; // DateTime to be rounded
var rounded = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, 0, 0);
```

You could fairly easily turn this into an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime HourPart(this DateTime value)
    {
        return new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, value.Hour, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Since FluentDateTime is on GitHub, perhaps you could contribute your change as well.

Comment: I was looking for an existing library. But it's a good idea, I might contribute to it. Thanks.